# Waiting for asynchrnous functions to end before continuing execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have two functions that do asynchronous things. When they have finished, I want to execute the rest of my code.

Of course if I do this:

```
myFuncA();
myFuncB();
// rest of my code
```

The rest is executed even if they didn't ended.

I tried this:

```
var a = false;
var b = false;

a = myFuncA(); // return true when it ends
b = myFuncB(); // return true when it ends

while (!a && !b) {
  // just waiting the two functions to end
}
// rest of my code
```

I expected the loop to end when the two functions end, but it doesn't work.

So I tried almost the same but with global variables:

```
var a = false;
var b = false;

myFuncA(); // value a = true when it ends
myFuncB(); // value b = true true when it ends

while (!a && !b) {
  // just waiting the two functions to end
}
// rest of my code
```

But it doesn't work either.

So my question is: what is the method for waiting for the results of async functions to continue the code execution?

Comment: Have you tried Promises?

Comment: Also async await could help you!

Comment: You can use jQuery Deferred and $.when.

Comment: Why do people always feel the need to suggest libraries and frameworks when this is a simple logical problem that can be resolved by simply using a callback.
@Simon Déchamps if you read this before you look at all these links, I suggest you can solve your problem easily by putting the rest of your code in a function C. Then in function A, you set a to True at the end, and check if b is also true, if yes, you trigger C().
In your function B, you set b to true at the end, and check if a is also true, if yes, you trigger C(). It will that way only execute once both have finished. Simple.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll check that. @zoubida13 you are right, I could even execute B in A callback, then C in B callback, or even have A, B and C code in only one function and falling from callback to callback since these functions are not made to be reused elsewhere. But I wanted my code to be more clear by splitting that big function into three (A and B are already handling callbacks in callbacks because of loops on HTTP requests and SQLite requests, so it's starting to make many callbacks). But your solution could be a good compromise.

Comment: @zoubida13 It's not so simple any more if you need to add error handling. Promises are neither a library nor a framework btw, they are the standardised solution to this problem.